# How do I hide the "next" button until a certain time has passed or video has finished playing?

Tags: javascript

I'm building an online survey on the [formr](https://formr.org/) platform. In the survey, the respondent is shown a video as an experimental treatment. I want to hide the "next" button until the respondent has watched the entire video, or a suitable time has passed to ensure that the respondent can't skip the treatment.

[I've been adviced to use JavaScript to solve this problem](https://github.com/rubenarslan/formr.org/issues/400), but I am very much a novice, and after a few hours of googling and some unsuccessful attempts, I turn to you.

Please let me know if I have left out necessary information.

Best

Comment: setTimeout(() => { //Show the button}, video time in milisecond)

Comment: Do you have to make sure the video is actually watched, e. g. can it be paused (a timer would not suffice) or seeked (the video finished would not suffice), what should happen when the user switches the tab, etc.

Comment: In an ideal world, the timer would pause when the user has switched tabs, but in practice it's not strictly necessary. A timer that counts down from say, 40 seconds, when the page with the video is loaded would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

If You Want to Show the Next Button After The Video (Assuming You are Using `<Video>` tag), Add a EventListener to fires when Video is ended. Write a Function to make That button Visible. And set **visibility** to **visible**

Like This:

```
var media = document.getElementById("myVideo");

media.addEventListener("ended", BtnVisible);

   function BtnVisible(){

            var btnVisible = document.getElementById("show");
            btnVisible.style.visibility = "visible";

   };
```

And The HTML :

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls id="myVideo">
                    <source src="sam.mp4">
</video>

<button id="show" style="visibility: hidden;">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a `<video>` tag you could bind to its `ended` event.

```
const video = document.querySelector('video');

video.addEventListener('ended', (event) => {
  const button = document.getElementById("nextButton");
  button.style.visibility = "visible";      
});
```